# YUI3 File size - How to determine?

Tags: yui

I read many times that YUI will load modules dynamically based on need. or based on parent module. Like [here](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/overlay/overlay-xy.html) it is written

> The overlay module will pull in the widget, widget-stack,
>   widget-position, widget-position-align, widget-position-constrain and
>   widget-stdmod extensions it uses.

So, how can I determine the final size of data getting downloaded for a web page due to YUI usage.

Actually I was thinking how one can compare the datasize of YUI with that of another library (JQuery).

Answer (score 3):

If you want file size vs functionality comparison, a close approximation based on features would be the simpleyui.js package (though the feature compilation is not 1:1), and be sure to look at gzip size as Tivac said.

Also keep in mind that JS lib file size comparison used as a reason to choose one over another is often a red herring.  Your site likely includes a number of images, many of which will easy be larger than the lib and several additional modules.  More relevant comparisons would be how the library is structured, what its relative strengths are, what's included out of the box (officially supported features vs 3rd party plugins), its community and documentation, etc.  Pretty much any lib will serve your basic DHTML needs, and neither you or your users will notice the difference.  Choose what works for you, and helps you build clean, maintainable code that you or your successor won't hate in a few months.

Comment: Need to check simpleYUI. I will check it when I have better knowledge of YUI.
File Size vs functionality comparison is important if size differs too much.

Answer (score 2):

The [Configurator](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/configurator/) will give you a file-size breakdown & automatically selects the needed modules.

Comment: I have only added base-base and node-base and it all counts to 92 KB.Is this looking correct? I think, minimum this two modules are required in any work!

Comment: Without gzip, yes. If you load the actual URL it generates & open Firebug to the network tab you'll see that over the wire it's more like 31K.